# std::cout corrupts variable

Tags: c++, cout, corruption

Short version: I have a variable called "number" (really), I print something without using that variable, and then it changes within the print function (checked by gdb).

Long version: Here are some code snippets:

cpu.cpp:

```
#include "cpu.hpp"

CPU::CPU(Cartridge cart): cart(cart) {
    PC = getMem(0xFFFC) + (getMem(0xFFFD) << 8);
}

unsigned char CPU::getMem(unsigned short addr) {return cart.getMem(addr);}
//...
```

cart.cpp:

```
//...
unsigned char Cartridge::getMem(unsigned short addr) {return (*mapper).getMem(addr);}
//...
```

mapper.cpp:

```
//...
unsigned char Mapper::getMem(unsigned short addr) {
    switch(number) {
        case 4:
        if(addr >= 0xE000) {
            unsigned int prgLocation = (((unsigned int)parent.prgSize) << 14) + addr;
            std::cout << "MAPPED INPUT ADDRESS " << "0x" << std::setw(4) << addr << " TO PRG ROM ADDRESS " << "0x" << std::setw(4) << prgLocation << ". \n";
            return parent.prg[prgLocation];
        } else {
            std::cerr << "ERROR: I DON'T RECOGNIZE ANYTHING AT ADDRESS " << "0x" << std::setw(4) << addr << "!\n";
            exit(3);
        }
        break;
        default:
        std::cerr << "ERROR: UNRECOGNIZED MAPPER " << "0x" << std::setw(2) << ((int)number) << "!\n";
        exit(2);
    }
}
```

cart.h (also contains Mapper):

```
#ifndef CART_HPP
#define CART_HPP
//...
class Mapper {
    private:
        unsigned short number;
        Cartridge parent;
    public:
        Mapper(Cartridge* cart, unsigned short number);
        unsigned char getMem(unsigned short addr);
        void setMem(unsigned short addr, unsigned char value);
        ~Mapper();
};
#endif
```

All of the variables used are initialized. "(*cart.mapper).number" is set to 4 before CPU is initialized, but, when run, this first outputs:

```
MAPPED INPUT ADDRESS 0xFFFC TO PRG ROM ADDRESS 0x4FFFC.
```

as expected (I have some formatting commands inside the Mapper initializer). What is not right is when the next invocation right after says:

```
ERROR: UNRECOGNIZED MAPPER 0xFC5C!
```

which seems to indicate that "number" has been changed. Running through gdb indicates that "number" gets changed within , but why? (Also, gdb says mapper 0xFADC, which is also mysterious.) As you can see, "number" doesn't get passed into the function.

I am running latest MinGW32 that I can through the latest MSYS I can on Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: If outputting to `std::cout` with a `<<` operator changes a value (which I really doubt) then it's either a really bad bug in the standard library (highly likely) or you have a really bad bug in *your* code somewhere (much more likely). The most likely alternative is that you go out of bounds of some memory or array somewhere in your code.

Comment: where is your declaration for "number"?

Comment: stack smashing? try enabling `-fsanitize=undefined`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is there any other windows based compiler suite that you know that I could use to test if it's the compiler's problem?

Comment: @realharry in mapper.cpp. "Mapper::Mapper(Cartridge* cart, int number): parent(*cart), number(number) {"

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot In compiling, it's not recognized, and in linking, it doesn't work.

Comment: Mapper header file might be useful.

Comment: @realharry Added it. Cartridge and Mapper are contained in the same file for technical reasons.

Comment: One thing I immediately notice is that `number` is declared as unsgined char whereas your ctor takes int. Is there a particular reason why you do that? In general, you will lose data by doing this (very likely unintentional) casting.

Comment: @realharry Good point. I need to change that, since I need to make that number at least a short, signed or not (since I only need 12 bits), but right now that's fine. I will try that though.

Comment: @realharry Did that, and put in more output that resulted.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious from the code fragments you posted. One thing I can say is that despite what you say _as you can see, "number" doesn't get passed into the function_, `number` _can_ change somewhere else since it's a member variable (e.g., in setMem()). I don't see any modification of "number", at least, in the example code, and if that's the case, then I suggest to make it `const` and see what happens.

Comment: Making it a `const` variable results in it getting set to `0xFFB0` normally and `0xFA30` in gdb.

Comment: @realharry which is odd, since it's supposed to be a constant... I definitely think that something is really wrong here.

Comment: @Rdrpenguin Probably so... BTW, I (try to) use more value types (no pointers) in C++ (although I don't really use C++ that much these days). It takes a bit of getting used to ("reference instead of pointer"), but I do believe it creates a safer program in general (less chance of memory-related errors). Just my personal preference.

Comment: @realharry The reason I need to use pointers is because Cartridge has a Mapper and Mapper points back to the Cartridge.